# QProgressDialog when setValue(0) is called

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.6

I have a class that is inherited from QProgressDialog. It sometimes crashes and its inside QProgressDialog class code.

I detected that when the `setValue(0);` is called in its constructor, crash happens. When I commented out this function, It does not crash. Even if setValue(0) is called after constructing of object crash still occurs.

This crash occurs when signals are emitted faster. Code piece shows how the function is called:

```
ProgressDialog progress(nullptr);
progress.setLabelText("Loading Result Files");
QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(myClassPtr,&myClass::myFunc);

QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(started()), &progress, SLOT(show()));
QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &progress, SLOT(hide()));
QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(transientAnimation, SIGNAL(progress(int)), &progress, SLOT(setValue(int)));

watcher.setFuture(future);

loop.exec();
```

progress signal is emitted inside myFunc() in another thread. In this function, multiple files are read in a folder and progress signal is emitted.

Why does this crash occur?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if removing that line helps to avoid the crash, why won't you simply call `setValue(0)` after the object is fully constructed? If that's inconvenient, you can schedule the call of `setValue(0)` at the end of the constructor via [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) or by a queued signal-slot connection. Or do you wish to understand why exactly the crash occurs?

Comment: I think it makes sense that when you try to change properties of an object while you are constructing it, bad things can happen.

Comment: Yeah, I know these but I want to understand that why exactly the crash occurs?

Comment: @Dmitry even setValue(0) is called after constructing of object, crash still occurs.

Comment: I can see there's [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31046) in Qt's bugtracker. It seems to be fixed but probably you encounter some different posing of things in which the bug still exists.

Comment: Yeah, it might be. Please remove minus point whoever gave, so people can look this issue more carefully..

Comment: Could you please show us a backtrace of the crash?

Comment: @Wilmort, Please write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that people can help you. Remove irrelevant code, and show us a minimum example that can reproduce the bug. This question can not be answered as it is, you don't even show where are the signals exactly emitted. Anyway, a common mistake is doing GUI operations from worker threads, so make sure you don't end up calling `setValue` from the thread pool, all GUI operations should happen in the GUI thread, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).